# Jquery, from "this", search the entire Dom tree for the next element with class, but stop at the first element matched element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

Im trying to click the next img with a certain class, ".photo" located within unordered elements.

I tried the but it loops over all images with class "photo" and stops at the last one, I want to stop when the next img is found after clicking it.

```
$('.'+current+'').parents().andSelf().nextAll().find('.photo').trigger('click');
```

How to do I check if any element with class has been matched while traversing?

Edit: And where possible, I understand that this is a heavy, how can I limit this search to certain elements to make it lighter?

Comment: It would be cool if you add code sample in a jsfiddle to try this out and help you...

Comment: I think you're looking for `.filter()`, not `.find()`. And use `.first()` to get only one.